# passing textbox values on the same page url without form or submit button using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, textbox

is there any ways to pass textbox values on the same page url without form or submit button i have `javascript function` but this `function` is working for `drop down values not for text box values?` i need to send textbox values on the same page url without form and submit button

now this is drop down page in this page dropdown values passing on the same page url but now i'm confused how can i send textbox values on the same page url without form or submit button using this javascript function?

```
function getComboB(sel) { 
var customers=document.getElementById("customers");
var value = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
addreceivable.action = "addreceivable.php?customers="+value+"";
addreceivable.submit();
}
<form name="addreceivable" id="addreceivable">
<select name="customers" id="customers">
<option value="Test">Test</option>
<option value="Demo">Demo</option>
<option value="Check">Check</option> 
</select>
<input type="submit" name="test" id="test" value="Submit">
</form>
```

now my problem is solved here i have completed my code passing textbox values on the same page url without submit button using javascript function

```
function getComboB(sel) { 
var textbox=document.getElementById("textbox");
var input_val = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
addreceivable.action = "test2.html?textbox="+input_val+"";
addreceivable.submit();
}

<form name="addreceivable" id="addreceivable">
<input name="textbox" class="textbox" onchange="getComboB();">
</form>
```

thanks to all friends!

Answer (score 1):

With textboxes use .val() to grab the value of it. I believe that is jQuery though so you might need that.

```
function getTextbox() {
   var textbox = $('input.textbox').val();
   //Do what you want with textbox now
}
<input name="textbox" class="textbox">
```

Comment: can u write example or javascript or jquery?

Comment: what about action which i used for form.action or form.submit?

Comment: @Frederik now happy i tag jquery as well :)

Comment: @FarhanAziz no problem, I thought you wanted a "not-jquery" solution :)

Comment: @Frederik i need to solve my problem whether it will be jq or js :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function getComboB(sel){
     //your other code
     //new code here
     var input_val = document.getElementById("id of your textbox").value;
}
```

You could use this to listen for changes in the text box:

```
document.getElementById("id of your textbox").addEventListener("change", getComboB);
```

The above line would listen for typing in the textbox and then call your function `getComboB()` at which point you would get the value of your textbox.